# Notepad++ numbering an array

Tags: notepad++

Is that possible to create an ordered list of arrays in Notepad++ using the following:

```
array[] =
array[] =
array[] =
array[] = 
array[] =
...
```

and obtain the following...

```
array[0] =
array[1] =
array[2] =
array[3] =
array[4] =
...
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
What I am actually wondering is, is there a practical way of doing it (by using replace all feature of Notepad++) using Notepad++. Not any other programming language. It is basically replace all [] symbols with ordered numbers in them.

Comment: Sure type it like that! If you mean using a language such as php then you'll have to be more specific

Comment: I think the original question tag "tips-n-tricks" or something, was appropriate for this question, although it was removed in BoltClock's first edit :/

Comment: Yeah, actually what I was looking for is a practical way of using something like replace all feature of Notepad++, by means of a regular expression to fill the brackets. As Luis Miguel Serrano also said, the tag "tips-n-tricks" was intentional.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Directly in notepad++ :

1. put your cursor between the two []
2. Press ALT to use column editing mode and go the last row with the mouse
3. Press simultaneously ALT + C to open Column / Multi Selection editor
4. Fill "Number to insert" with 0 to n and press OK

It's done !!

Comment: thanks for the great post.. it's nice to learn such a feature. But it's a little different at the last step (enter the starting number and increment amount), which is not really a crucial difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a practical way of doing it in Notepad++ but there is another trick that might be used for those who have Excel installed. Create an excel spreadsheet and copy the following structures as much as you want.

```
array[
array[
...
array[
```

then from 0 to n, generate numbers in the next column and paste ] character to the adjacent column. So in the end you have

```
array[ 0 ]
array[ 1 ]
...
array[ n ]
```

now copy the above 3 columns to a notepad++ file and replace spaces with empty string..